# About ansible's forks configuration in large scale deployment environment

Tags: ansible

The default value of ansible forks configuration option is 5. In a large scale (2000) nodes, I would like to enlarge it to 2000 so that all target nodes can run a play in parallel. My question is that is forks=2000 acceptable? Is it too large?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it may be feasible, but I'd be aware of that many forks, as you can read in this  [article](https://opensource.com/article/19/3/ansible-performance), it may prove problematic:

> You might run into problems when it comes to performance and capacity, such as limits to memory and CPU. One thing you might want to think about when dealing with scaling up to larger and larger numbers is the negative impact to your downstream—because asking that number of systems to accomplish a task could prove problematic. For example, asking 300–500 systems to accomplish a task like fetching a file, even from a single source, may exhaust that resource, causing failure.

What you could to is break that into smaller batches and have them rolling a group at a time, say every 25% of your fleet or so. This is also the recommended approach for updates.
I haven't found anything on a Forking limit hard number in the documentation.
Also a little about this in this [ansible article](https://www.ansible.com/blog/ansible-performance-tuning)

Comment: Thanks, and agree. We do encountered ansible stuck at copying file to remote. May be the performance of scp/sftp is a bottleneck. I will dig it more.